# wp_insert_post inside save_post adds wrong metadata to inserted post

Tags: post-meta, wp-insert-post, save-post

I have code for saving metadata for Student post_type. While saving metadata I also want to add separate posts for each payment in payments array:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_student_meta' );

function save_student_meta( $post_id ) {

    // Code gathering data form $_POST 

    // [...]

    $student_id = $post_id;
    $meta_key = '_student_name'; 
    $meta_value = $student_name,

    update_post_meta( $student_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );



    // For each payment add Payments post into database

    foreach( $student_payments as $payment ) {

        $postarr = array(
            'post_title'=>'empty',
            'post_content'=>'empty',
            'post_type'=>'payments',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'meta_input'=>array(
                '_payment_date'=>$payment['date'],
                '_payment_amount'=>$payment['amount'],
                '_payment_status'=>$payment['status'],
                '_payment_student_id'=>$student_id
            )
        );

        wp_insert_post( $postarr, true );

    }

}
```

Problem is, in database every Payment's post has also Student's metadata:

Payment post meta:

- '_payment_date'
- '_payment_amount'
- '_payment_status'
- '_payment_student_id'
- '_student_name' **<- should not be saved with Payment post**

What could be problem here?

Comment: hmm your code block is incomplete, otherwise this should generate an infinite loop that ends with a fatal error. The fact this does not happen means that super important parts of the code have been removed. Please include the entire function ( including the parts you consider irrelevant )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is the `save_post` loop. When you call `wp_insert_post`, it triggers `save_post` and thus inserts the student meta.

what you can do is, to check if the post type is correct while inserting the meta.

like:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_student_meta', 10, 2 );

function save_student_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( 'student' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
    // Code gathering data form $_POST
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added post_type check inside save_student_meta() and it works. Thanks

Comment: You can mark it as accepted answer